# Neo4j DB indexing

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher

I have this little graph:

```
CREATE (Thing:Class {title:'Thing'})
CREATE (Places:Class{title:'Places'})
CREATE (Lemma:Class {title:'Lemma'})
CREATE (Country:Class {title:'Country'})
CREATE (Region:Class {title:'Region'})
CREATE (loc1:Index {title:'loc00001'})
CREATE (loc1_1:Index {title:'loc00001.01'})
CREATE (Abc:Placename {title:'Abc', gender:'n'})
CREATE
  (Thing)-[:HAS_SUBCLASS]->(Places),
  (Thing)-[:HAS_SUBCLASS]->(Lemma),
  (Places)-[:HAS_SUBCLASS]->(Country),
  (Country)-[:HAS_SUBCLASS]->(Region),
  (Country)-[:HAS_SUBCLASS]->(Region),
  (Places)-[:HAS_INDIVID]->(loc1),
  (loc1)-[:HAS_LA_VAR]->(loc1_1),
  (loc1_1) -[:HAS_VAR_NAME]->(Abc)


RETURN Thing
;
```

If I want to start my query from a specific node, let's say **loc1** , I need to index it:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Index(title)
```

Then I query my DB:

```
START n=node:Index(title='loc00001') MATCH n RETURN n
```

Here I get the error:

> Index `Index` does not exist
>
> Neo.ClientError.Schema.NoSuchIndex

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing [legacy indexes with Lucene](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/indexing.html) and [schema indexes](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/labels). As the Lucene indexes are deprecated within Neo4j, I'm not going to mention them any further. If you use `CREATE INDEX ON :Index(title)`, you are trying to create a schema index on label 'Index' and its property 'title'. As you're using labels like e.g. Class, Index, Placename etc., your statement should like like:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Class(title)
CREATE INDEX ON :Index(title)
... for every label you want to index ...
```

You shouldn't explicitly mention the index in your query, it will be used automatically

```
MATCH (n:Thing{title:'loc00001'}) 
RETURN n
```

although you can hint in case you want to

```
MATCH (n:Thing)
USING INDEX n:Thing(title)
WHERE n.title='loc00001'
RETURN n
```

Comment: Thank you! Queries you wrote work. So, for querying I cannot use START clauses with my DB?

Comment: You can still use START, but not in combination with schema indexes. START can be used with id's like `START n=node(1)` or legacy indexes like `START n=node:nodeIndexName(key={value})`.